# High CPU usage while sampling microphone on java?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, cpu-usage, javax.sound.sampled

I am playing with the microphone to sample eg my voice. For that I use the javax.sound.sampled pacakge.

However, when only sampling the microphone, I have a very high CPU usage.
The code is available here :

```
http://91.121.120.36:8081/root/gui-freq/blob/6b470aaf03038562578e4386c6774fbaca9f1fbc/src/main/java/fr/lelouet/audio/sampler/MicSampler.java
```

The only code executed in the main is the following :

```
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open();
        line.start();
        float[] newSamples = new float[samplesBufferSize];
        byte[] copybuffer = new byte[newSamples.length * SAMPLE_SIZE_BYTE];
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (run) {
            // synchronized so we don't have a problem of collecting the data when
            // we should be stopped.
            synchronized (LISTENLOCK) {
                long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
                line.read(copybuffer, 0, copybuffer.length);
                long read = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (int i = 0; i < newSamples.length; i++) {
                    // convert the buffer of 2 bytes to an int
                    newSamples[i] = copybuffer[SAMPLE_SIZE_BYTE * i] << 8
                            | copybuffer[SAMPLE_SIZE_BYTE * i + 1] & 0xFF;
                }
                long convert = System.currentTimeMillis();
                addSamples(newSamples);
                long add = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.err.println("delay=" + (begin - lastTime) + " read="
                        + (read - begin) + " convert=" + (convert - read) + " add="
                        + (add - convert));
                lastTime = add;
            }
        }
```

I use System.err to debug the CPU usage values, which gives me something like :

```
delay=1 read=788 convert=0 add=0
```

meaning the code use most of the time in the line.read call.

meanwhile top returns 120% CPU time for java.

I find this high CPU usage too expensive. It seems to me the code will actively seek for data in a while(true) loop. Am I wrong ? How should I change my code ?

EDIT :

I added a wait before reading data :

```
                long remaining = copybuffer.length - line.available();
                while (remaining > 0) {
                    long ms = (long) (1000 * remaining / format.getSampleRate() / SAMPLE_SIZE_BYTE);
                    if (ms > 5) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(ms);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    remaining = copybuffer.length - line.available();
                }
```

I now have <5% CPU usage, and most of time is spent in the waiting loop instead of read(). It confirms the read() contains an active loop.

Comment: According to the JavaDoc the `read` method will block until all required bytes are read. Thus you might try and read only the data that is available, i.e. call `available()` and use the returned value as a parameter to the `read()` call.

Comment: Depending on whats happening in the while loop - it can be very memory and cpu-consuming. For instance - creating an object there. Just a tip - be very cautious during this circumstance

Comment: OK, I add a wait until available() returns enough data (in main post)
Seems like the read() is blocking but with an active while() inside.

Comment: never use the `available()` method, it's pretty broken.

Comment: what else should I use then ?